# How to highlight recyclerview item when using MVVM architecture and databinding?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I'm trying to highlight a recyclerview item while adhering to MVVM principles and while using databinding. But I'm having trouble understanding how to handle selecting a row.

I currently pass my recyclerview item onclick to the viewmodel using the following interface:

```
public interface ItemClickListener
{
    void onItemClicked(String id);
}
```

The view onclick is databound:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="model"
            type="Item" />

        <variable
            name="listener"
            type="ItemClickListener" />
    </data>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{model.name}"
        android:onClick="@{() -> listener.onItemClicked(model.name)}" />
</layout>
```

The viewmodel implements the interface so I have a reference to the Item. The listener is instantiated in the activity and passed into the adapter.

How would I handle selecting a recyclerview item (and giving it a background colour)? Should the viewholder implement onClickListener(View view) and pass it through my interface along with it's position?

Answer (score 3):

In an MVVM architecture, your UI is driven by the data exposed by your ViewModel. In your particular case, that means that the `Item` that you are displaying in your ViewHolder should be able to tell if it is selected or not. To do that, the simplest solution is to add a `isSelected` boolean to your `Item` class. That boolean will allow you to decide which `backgroundColor` to use in your layout.

To link everything together in an MVVM way, your `ItemClickListener` implementation should modify your ViewModel's `List<Item>` by toggling the `isSelected` boolean of the Item that was just clicked.

If you are using the architecture components LiveData, make sure to post the new value of the List, which I assume would notify your Adapter of the change. If you don't do it, your UI will not get refreshed since the RecyclerView will not be aware of a change in the Data being displayed.